# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha mas reciente de un producto en mysql y php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, select

necesito realizar un SELECT en mysql en donde necesito que me devuelva un valor del producto mas reciente que se ha agregado a partir del nombre del usuario.

My base de datos

La tabla se llama **cobro mensual**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que el SELECT me devuelva el **nombre** de la persona y la **fecha mas reciente** de la columna **corte1** a partir del nombre que se vaya a buscar en este caso Freddy Martinez Martinez.

Estoy utilizando este comando

$consulta = "SELECT nombre,MAX(corte1) FROM cobro_mensual WHERE nombre LIKE '%$nombre%'";

Cuando realizo la consulta me da como resultado la fecha mas antigua :(

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, se lo agradecería bastante.

Comment: Me sigue dando el dato mas antiguo, que otra manera sería ideal para realizar la búsqueda por nombre y que de la fecha mas reciente.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que tu tabla no está normalizada, por eso el orden no funciona.

La mejor solución a esto sería normalizar la tabla, haciendo que `corte1` y todas las columnas que estén destinadas a guardar fechas sean del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`.

Si no es posible normalizar, entonces deberás convertir el valor de la columna a fecha, podrías hacerlo usando [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Y esto tendrá que ser así siempre que quieras comparar o hacer cálculos basados en fechas, por eso lo más recomendable es normalizar tus datos, lo que implicaría declararlos del tipo propio y consiguientemente guardarlos en el formato admitido por el manejador (Año-Mes-Día) para las fechas. Con los datos normalizados no tendrás que hacer ninguna conversión y los cálculos y comparaciones funcionarán siempre de la forma esperada.

Esta consulta te convierte la cadena que hay en `corte1` a una fecha válida, usando el formato que tienen esas fechas:

```
$consulta = "SELECT 
        nombre,
        STR_TO_DATE(corte1,'%m/%d/%Y')) AS maxDate
    FROM cobro_mensual 
    WHERE nombre LIKE '%$nombre%'";
```

Otro problema de no tener datos normalizados es que es muy fácil que se comentan errores, tu columna `corte1` admitiría valores como `40/30/ABCD` sin ningún problema.